# PersistenceException cause and detailmessage

Tags: jpa, spring-data

I am trying to find out the name of the entity that failed while doing a insert .
From the persistnceexception I can get the detail message as 
**org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:  could not insert: [ com.mycompany.car ]** 
I am able to retrieve the name of the entity but from this message

When I try to do the same thing in another environment ( with spring data jpa ) , the persistence exception , the detail message is different
**org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'OVCAR-3' for key 'citymst_un'**

I tried looking at PersistenceExceptionTranslator but could not find any details
Is there any setting which controls the messages of the PersistenceException

Answer (score 0):

That's not a matter of environment. That's a different exception. Spring does nothing but wrap the original exception into a `DataAccessException`. So if the original exception does not contain a descriptive message there's hardly anything we can do about that. I suggest to file an issue with Hibernate to include the entity type into `ConstraintViolationException`s it throws.

To solve your issue at hand: is `OVCAR-3` and `citymst_un` not enough hint to find out which of your domain types fails to persist? I mean, you can probably dig down from the repository you're using, can't you?